# xpages: after appearance I need to press a button 2 times before action executes

Tags: xpages

I have a button in a dialog. the appearance (visibility) is computed and depending on the number of characters entered in an input field (onchange event i perform a partial refresh on panel that contains the button).

However when the button appears I need to press it 2 times before the action on the button executes OR I have to click somewhere in the dialog and then click the button.

I do not see any errors via logreader application.

What should I do to have the button executable after appearance?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen, IIRC dojo was eating some click events, but can't recall specifics or what the solution was...

But it's better to do this sort of hide/show on client side JS and minimise traffic to-from the server, for client performance reasons.
Something like this should work:

```
<input id="myInput" name="myInput" />
<button id="myButton" style="display: none">Save</button>

<script>
  const btn = document.querySelector("#myButton");
  document.querySelector("#myInput").addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    btn.style.display = event.target.value.length > 10 ? "" : "none";
  });
</script>
```